# Ruby web automation is failing

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I have a Ruby automation script that used to work with selenium-webdriver and watir-webdriver on Linux.

A few days ago, one of my scripts crashed and, since then, web automations stopped working.

I am now getting the following error:

```
Headless display: :99
D, [2016-11-22T12:59:42.668070 #16284] DEBUG -- : end of file reached (EOFError)
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
/home/batch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:103:in `response_for'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:57:in `request'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:653:in `raw_execute'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:124:in `create_session'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:88:in `initialize'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:41:in `initialize'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `new'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `for'
/home/batch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:82:in `for'
test.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

I tried to reinstall both selenium-webdriver and watir-webdriver gems and it did not help.

I  compared all .rb files in the error message with the files on the production server and they are exactly the same.

Here is the test code I am running:

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'
require 'logger'

headless = Headless.new(autopick: true, reuse: false, destroy_at_exit: true).start
puts "Headless display: #{ENV['DISPLAY']}"

logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

begin
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 600 # seconds - default is 60
    d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :http_client => client, :switches => %w[--disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate]
    b = Watir::Browser.new d

    saved_cookies = b.cookies.to_a

    site_url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    puts site_url
    b.goto site_url
    sleep 2
    b.close
    exit
rescue  => err
      logger.debug(err)
end
```

This code works fine on other servers.
It feels like something got corrupted, but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely not using the latest chromedriver (right now it is 2.25). Make sure you are getting the correct one here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

"watir-webdriver" code has been renamed to just be "watir", so you should upgrade to use Watir 6.0 with `require 'watir'`

Also, you can initialize a Watir::Browser without creating a driver first:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 600
switches = %w[--disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate]
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, {http_client: client, switches: switches}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I mentioned before, this environment was working few days ago. I cannot make the changes you are suggesting since the dev environmet has to match the production one.

Comment: What version of Chrome & what version of chromedriver? Most of the EOFError I've seen are a result of mismatched versions. I don't understand the dev vs production issue, since both will be independent of how you are black-box testing with Selenium.

Comment: During the OS upgrade the versions of few modules and Chrome got out of sync. After everything was brought to proper versions, Ruby started to operate properly. Thank you.